# Around 1750, How many Native Americans (if any) spent the winter in the Keweenaw Peninsula, Michigan?

Tags: 18th-century, native-americans, colonial-america, north-america

This is the Keweenaw Peninsula in Michigan:

[image]

[image]

I've been reading about it's history during the colonial era. Apparently the Native Americans mined copper from this area because there were great copper deposits near the surface.

**I'd like to know if any Native Americans spent the winter there, and if so, about how many? What tribes did so? Just Ojibwe, or others?** Were there perhaps even permanent settlements where they grew corn or other stuff?

The year I'm interested in is around 1750. If it matters, the exact area I'm interested in is the southern half of the peninsula---both coastlines and the inland area.

(I have many similar questions for this time period about Native American history in many areas in North America. If anyone knows some good books about that, don't hesitate to recommend them.)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this area might not have been settled:

> There is also an ancient superstition concerning Keweenaw point which
>   prevented the Indians from settling there. It was the general belief
>   that the Evil Manitou resided there and the point does not appear to
>   have been inhabited by the Indians but was only visited by them at
>   certain times for the purpose of obtaining copper Then by ceremonious
>   rites and offerings to the Evil Spirit permission was obtained from
>   him by the priests to dig for copper.

and...

> ...It is not improbable that the scarcity of game in the wilderness on
>   Keweenaw point may have added to the Indians aversion to settlement
>   upon that peninsula but fish are abundant enough near its shores so
>   that they could have lived there had they chosen to do so.

- from [Message from the President of the United States to the Two
  Houses ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=XEBFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA375&dq=indians%20of%20keweenaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVkvqD1Y_SAhUS0IMKHSohA9oQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=indians%20of%20keweenaw&f=false), Volume 3, 1849

The above source has more information concerning the early explorations of this region, covering the Jesuits, French and British presences, and the Native Americans beliefs and legends concerning the copper deposits.

- ...more on the [Manitou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manitou) and use of [copper in worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontonagon_Boulder) practices
- ...and a [great map resource](http://www.emersonkent.com/images/indian_tribes.jpg) from the comment by TED

---

Another source mentions a wintering area that was used, located just south of the area shown on the OP's map:

> As near as can be determined, these winter quarters of the Ottawas
>   were in the vicinity of L'Anse at the head of Keweenaw Bay.

- from [A history of the upper peninsula of Michigan](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/micounty/ARW8562.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext)

Comment: If that's true, then they almost surely did not spend the winter there. The quote is 99 years late, but if it's an ancient superstition then it's just as well. But maybe I need to ask exactly where the Huron and Ojibwe spent the winter?

Comment: According to this [handy-dandy map of native tribal territory](http://www.emersonkent.com/images/indian_tribes.jpg), that peninsula was firmly inside Ojibwa territory. So if they didn't winter there, likely nobody did.

Comment: The Huron(Wyandot) seem to be farther east then this area, and mainly north of the great lakes, so not on the above map.

Comment: BTW: If anyone else is as curious as I was "Manitou" used in this way seems to mean "spirit". Alone, it appears to be equivalent to the Siouxan "Wakonda", both of which are similar concepts to The Force in Star Wars (although Christians like to equate them to their God).

Comment: @T.E.D. What year does that map represent? And I can't tell the difference between the two shades of pink. Which tribe/pink surrounds the Great Lakes?

Comment: @user2448131 Can anyone find a alternate source for the evil manitou presence belief? I've been googling things like Keweenaw Evil Manitou with no results.

Comment: @DrZ214 - I went looking for it, and came up 0. However, I did find [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=66BcyLtUXHsC&pg=PT66&lpg=PT66&dq=Keweenaw+point+ojibwa&source=bl&ots=bxegMdn-_B&sig=jmH8OOwWrJygM_j7aB_kERS9RM8&hl=xx-bork&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAib2TrJfSAhUB4yYKHUCgA1kQ6AEIRzAJ#v=onepage&q=Keweenaw%20point%20ojibwa&f=false), which suggests they also used the area as a seasonal source of berries. Obviously that wouldn't be available there in the winter.

Comment: ...Oh, and I would suggest an alternate modern English translation of "Evil Manitau" as "this place is strong with the Dark Side of The Force". :-)